# Process list and write output to files named after list members

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to run a command which accepts a list of names. It should go through each member of the list and then output it to a text file in a specific location, and the name of that text file will be the member name from the list. Then the script continues to the next member run the command on it, and then write the output to a text file whose name will be the 2<sup>nd</sup> member in the list.

I'm sure a loop is involved, and perhaps a temporary variable which I have no idea how to declare :(

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content "C:\ServerList.txt") -ScriptBlock {
  Servermanagercmd.exe -query roles.xml
} -credential baloon\yellow | Out-File C:\OutputF.txt
```

Comment: you will need to post the code that you are currently running.

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment i'm posting the cmd now

Comment: You want to split output in own separate file per `ComputerName`?

Comment: Well exactly what i would like is the output files that are being created each have a unique name which ideally i'd like it to be the computer name.

Answer (score 4):

Pull out the `Get-Content` of the serverlist file so the server name values are available down the pipeline:

```powershell
Get-Content c:\serverlist.txt | Where {$_} |
    Foreach { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -Scriptblock {...} -Credential baloon\yellow |
              Out-File "$_.txt" }
```

Note that the `Where {$_}` is to weed out any empty lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Shall I assume this issue is that the data that is being output has no context since you wont know what system it is from?

```powershell
$outputfile = C:\OutputF.txt
Set-Content -Path $outputfile -Value ""
ForEach($server in (Get-Content "C:\ServerList.txt")){

    Add-Content -Path $outputfile -Value "Server: $server"
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Servermanagercmd.exe -query roles.xml} -credential baloon\yellow | 
        Add-Content -Path $outputfile
}
```

Wipe the file to start new (remove this if you dont want to erase the file.). For each server in your list add the server name on its own line in the file and then run the `Invoke-Command` also sending its output to file.

This will might be inefficient depending on the number of server you are checking. At that point I would consider using jobs.

**Update**

After reading Keith Hills answer I realize that I misread your question. My logic would output all to one file with the server name separating the contents. You actually wanted separate files.